# Setting up Xdebug in a VSCode instance attached to a docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I want to set up a development environment for WordPress which supports IDE debugging through Xdebug and is contained in a docker container.

1. I'm working from WSL2 / Ubuntu 18.04
2. I'm using a MySQL official image
3. I'm using a WordPress image built on top of the WordPress official image with **Xdebug installed through PECL**
4. I'm **copying configuration files for php.ini and xdebug.ini from a local folder**
5. After launching my container I'm attaching a VSCode instance to the container by using *ms Remote Containers extensions*
6. I'm installing the official PHP debug VSCode extension from the Xdebug team in the attached instance of VSCode
7. I'm automatically generating a launch.json file for PHP
8. I'm setting a breakpoint and launching the debugger by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>

What happens is that the debugger starts, offering me to open a browser at the port I set for Xdebug (9003), but the page doesn't load, the breakpoint isn't reached and the debugger tab in VSCode shows several errors such as: `Failed initializing connection 1: connection closed (on close)`

I tried other slightly different methods such as having the dockerfile build Xdebug from source as well as other setups for the ini files from tutorials found on the internet, but the end result is always the same.

If I try to run `xdebug_info()` through the browser I get a normal output, if I try to run the file from console I get this error:

> `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

which is in line with similar errors I get in the docker-compile output.

I tried forwarding the 9003 port with docker-compile, but the behavior didn't change.

These are my docker and config files:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.6"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: 
      context: ./wordpress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      # - "9003:9003"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

*wordpress/Dockerfile*

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install git
    
# RUN git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf git://github

RUN pecl install xdebug

COPY ../config/ /

RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

*wordpress/config/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini* (edited from php.ini-development)

```
...
[Xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

(Since it seems this isn't being tracked I also tried making a symbolic link from php.ini-development to php.ini from the container console, then adding the variables there.)

*wordpress/config/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini*

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug,trace,profile,coverage
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host='host.docker.internal'
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```